# Vue 3 (With laravel and interia) file Input wont clear after onsuccess event

Tags: php, html, vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-10

When I try to reset the file input control after files are uploaded it still shows the number and name of the files uploaded. I have a button that resets it manually and that works as expected, but when I put that same function on an OnSuccess event it clears the array in the form but the control still shows the images which I would like to be reset for the next upload.

I'm thinking this is due to the event firing before the input box is reloaded but I can't be sure, am I wrong?

```
<template>
<Box>
    <template #header>Upload Images</template>
    <form
        @submit.prevent="upload">
        <!--enctype="multipart/form-data"
        method="POST"
        :action="route('realtor.listing.image.store', {listing: listing.id})">-->
        <section class="flex items-center gap-2 my-4">
            <input
                class="border rounded-md file:px-4 file:py-2 border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 file:text-gray-700 file:dark:text-gray-400 file:border-0 file:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 file:font-medium file:hover bg-gray-200 file:dark:hover:bg-gray-700 file:hover:cursor-pointer file:mr-4"
                type="file"
                multiple
                @load="reset"
                @input="addFiles"
            />

            <button class="btn-outline disabled:opacity-45"
                    type="submit"
                    :disabled="!canUpload"
            >Upload
            </button>

            <button class="btn-outline"
                    type="reset"
                    @click="reset"
            >Reset
            </button>

        </section>
        <div v-if="imageErrors.length" class="input-error">
            <div v-for="(error, index) in imageErrors" :key="index">
                {{ error }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</Box>

<!-- Image Gallery box -->
<Box v-if="listing.images.length" class="mt-4">
    <template #header> Current Listing Images</template>
    <section class="mt-4 grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">

        <div v-for="image in listing.images"
             :key="image.id"
             class="flex flex-col justify-between">

            <img :src="image.src" class="rounded-md" alt=""/>
            <Link :href="route('realtor.listing.image.destroy', {listing: props.listing.id, image: image.id})"
            method="delete"
            as="button"
            class="mt-2 btn-outline text-sm"
            >Delete
            </Link>
        </div>
    </section>
</Box>
</template>

<script setup>

import Box from "@/Components/UI/Box.vue";
import {Link, useForm} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import {computed, ref} from "vue";
import {router} from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import NProgress from "nprogress"
import {value} from "lodash/seq.js";

const props = defineProps({listing: Object})

router.on('progress', (event) => {
if (event.detail.progress.percentage) {
    NProgress.set((event.detail.progress.percentage / 100) * 0.9)
}
})

const form = useForm({
images: [],
})

const imageErrors = computed(() => Object.values(form.errors))

const canUpload = computed(() => form.images.length)
const upload = () => {
form.post(
    route('realtor.listing.image.store', {listing: props.listing.id}),
    {

        onSuccess: () => {
            return form.reset('images') + console.log('onsuccess');
        },

    },
)
}

const addFiles = (event) => {
for (const image of event.target.files) {
    form.images.push(image)
    }
}

const reset = () => form.reset('images') + console.log('reset');

</script>
```

I tried using the @load event but that also did not work, I can't seem to find a list of events to track its execution order.

I also hooked the functions up to console log to make sure they were running.